useradd: group 'pulse-access' does not exist
I always have the group 'pulse' & 'pulse-access' in my system. Ref, here:
===> Creating groups.
Creating group 'pulse' with gid '563'.
Creating group 'pulse-access' with gid '564'.
Creating group 'pulse-rt' with gid '557'.

and here:

for systemwide mode, multi-user access configuration should be created in ~/.config/pulse/system.pa instead of ~/.config/pulse/default.pa. And users should be added to pulse-access group

But in KUbuntu 24.04 LTS, both such groups are gone, and my useradd command failed with:
useradd: group 'pulse' does not exist
useradd: group 'pulse-access' does not exist

Are such pulse groups still exist for the pulse packages in Ubuntu 24.04? I need them as commented here, I need systemwide mode, multi-user access to pulse, and any account can play sound on that computer.

Hasn't Ubuntu migrated to Pipewire? Is pulseaudio even installed now?

Ah, yes. That's why. thx.
